# How to convert string to string array[] in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

i have a string variable which receives data from web the data is in the from of string like this

```
string output="[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]";
```

i want to convert it into a string array [] so that i can specify each element via for each loop

```
string output;
into
string[] out;
```

PS: if any predefined method is there that will also help

Comment: You are looking for `String.Split`.

Comment: I think would be usefull for you before asking any question do a little search on google.  Google is you best friend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that using `Trim` And `Split`:

```
var out = output.TrimStart('[').TrimEnd(']').Split(',');
```

But your data looks like `JSON` string. So, if you are dealing with `JSON` instead of making your own parser try using libraries that already does that such as [`JSON.NET`](http://james.newtonking.com/json).

Comment: yes i am dealing with json but array can also work as JSON is in array [] not as a object {}

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Trim` functions to remove brackets and then use `Split()` function to get the string array that contains the substrings in this string that are delimited by elements of a specified Unicode character.

```
var res  = output.TrimStart('[')
                 .TrimEnd(']')
                 .Split(',');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] arr = output.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
output.Substring(1, output.Length - 2).Split(',');
```